# Kendo Datepicker converting to jQuery post a date value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In javascript I get the date from my kendo datetime

```
var myDate = $("#mydate").getKendoDatePicker().value();
```

(Looks like this)
Fri May 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Then I try to post it to ASP.NET MVC using jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        url: "/HeaderData",

        data: myDate,

        success: successHeaderData,

        dataType: 'json'

    });
```

But the date is not parsed by the Action in MVC.

How do I convert the "Fri May 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" into a date that ASP.NET MVC will accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the method `.toJSON()` to convert to an ISO format date

```
var myDate = $("#mydate").getKendoDatePicker().value().toJSON();
```

outputs `"2015-05-30T06:41:32.576Z"`

Answer (score 0):

Make value stored in string.

> Blockquote

Use The Method ToShortDateString() in your c#
a.ValidFromA = a.ValidFrom.ToShortDateString();

> Blockquote

ValidFromA-String
ValidFrom-DateTime